# send Request and get response from php in my asp.net

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My website is Asp.net mvc and I want to use one Company post my Product 
their web is php and web service is php in document is clear how use php but I want call php functions and get response on my asp website how can I send request

```
<?PHP    
  $soap = new SoapClient("http://www.froservice.ir/F-W-S-L/F_Gateway.php?wsdl");    
  $ResNum = $_REQUEST['ResNum'];
  $RefNum = $_REQUEST['RefNum'];
  $State = $_REQUEST['State'];     
  $VerifyUrl = "http://www.YourSite/verify.php";     
 $Res = $soap->FVerifyEndbuy($ResNum,$RefNum,$State,$VerifyUrl,$Username,$Password);
 $Res=urldecode($Res);
 echo $Res;    
?>
```

how  call this function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a service reference to your MVC project. Right-click References, Add Service Reference, use the soap client URL. You will then have a class that you can call methods on like any other class. But I wouldn't guarantee that service is completely interoperable with ASP.NET service references. If it doesn't work, you can always build a request and parse the response manually with [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)